# Помогите реализовать сортировку методом выбора (char) с N-ленточным слиянием

Tags: c++

Не пойму как реализовать это N-ленточным слияние. Сортировка методом выбора с ключевым полем записи - char. Помогите пожалуйста!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

// сортировка методом выбора
void select(char *mass, int N) {
    int a, b, c, exchange;
    char t;
    for (int a = 0; a < N-1; a++)
    {
        exchange = 0;
        c = a;
        t = mass[a];
        for (int b = a+1; b < N; b++)
        {
            if (mass[b] < t)
            {
                c = b;
                t = mass[b];
                exchange = 1;
            }
        }
        if (exchange = 1)
        {
            mass[c] = mass[a];
            mass[a] = t;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    int N;
    char *mass;
    cout << ("Input N: ");
    cin >> N;
    mass = (char*)malloc((N) * sizeof(char));
    cout << ("Input elements: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cin >> mass[i];
    }
    select(mass, N);//сортировка
    printf("Sorted: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%c ", mass[i]);
    }
    free(mass);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что за смесь  - так слияние или выбором? В любом случае надо самому начать работу, чтобы ответы были не на пустом месте.

Comment: @MBo в том и проблема, что нужно сделать слиянием, а каждую ленту сортировать методом выбора

Comment: В чём реальная проблема? Сортировка выбором проста. Она уже сделана?

Comment: @MBo сортировка сделала, нужно сделать слияние

Comment: @MBo добавил свой код, посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

После того, как сделана сортировка выбором в каждой "ленте" - векторе, или массиве, эти векторы упорядочены.

Создаётся структура данных "очередь по приоритетам" - обычно на основе двоичной кучи, в неё складываются пары `(номер вектора nv; idx индекс = 0)`, сравнение идёт по значению `A[nv][idx]`

На каждом шаге из кучи извлекается вершина - индекс элемента с наименьшим значением, его значение добавляется к результату, если возможно, то индекс увеличивается на 1, и пара опять загоняется в кучу

```
while prqueue.count > 0:
     p = prqueue.extracttop
     result.add(A[p.nv][p.idx])
     if p.idx < p.nv.length - 1:
        p.idx++
        prqueue.insert(p)
```

Comment: А можно воспользоваться стандартным алгоритмом std::merge :  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/?kw=merge

Comment: @Alexey Nikolaev Да, можно, только придётся организовать попарное слияние по этапам